# Saving a hashed string in Salesforce?

Tags: hash, salesforce, sha256, apex-code

Not a SFDC expert but need to integrate a web form hosted in SFDC. For other reasons, this page needs to capture an initial password and send off the salted/sha256'd version of the password to another system or a human. I don't want to save the cleartext obviously.

What's the lightest touch way to hash the password before saving? I could do this in the browser except that I don't want to rely on Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex has a `Crypto` class which has a `generateDigest` method you need, something like:

```
Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(passwordString));
```

Comment: That should do the trick. Can this be attached to a save action?

Comment: Yes, you can either use a trigger approach shown by Chris or you can write a custom method instead of default save() which will calculate the hash and then call controller's save().

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should add this code to an apex trigger.

```
trigger on sObject(before insert){
  for(sObject s: trigger.new){
    s.Hash__c = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(s.passwordString__c));
    s.passwordString__c = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to encrypt a string to SHA256 hash format :

```
//value to process
Blob data= Blob.valueOf('Any String');
```

**or in case of field value**

```
Blob data= Blob.valueOf(sObject.FieldAPIName));
Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', data);
//Convert SHA-256 Hash data to String
String encryptedString =EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me =>

```
String abc = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(
             Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', 
             Blob.valueOf('test String')));
```